# Excel VBA save/restore last search term

Tags: excel, find, vba

Is there a way to save/restore the last (user defined) search term when using the Cells.Find method in Excel VBA?

**Example:**

- The user is searching for "*foo*" with the find dialog (CTRL-F).
- Later he can repeat his search by simply pressing CTRL-F and ENTER. (The search term will still be there.)
- But **if a macro uses Cells.Find** to search for "*bar*", the **search term will be replaced**.
- Now the user can not simply repeat his search for "*foo*" anymore because the find dialog is starting with "*bar*" as search term.

Maybe the user has even forgotten which word or number he was searching for at the last time? In this case the old search term in the dialog box would be very helpful.

**My solution for Word is simple:**

```
' // Save the last user defined search term.
strSearchTermBackup = Selection.Find.Text

With Selection.Find
    .Text = "bar"
    [...]
End With

' // Restore the last user defined search term.
Selection.Find.Text = strSearchTermBackup
```

Unfortunately this seems not to be possible in Excel. I get only compiler errors like "*argument not optional*".

Do I miss something very simple here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: After user does ctrl-f and excel selects the found cell, store activecell to a variable?

Comment: Can you show the code you're using in Excel? NOte that the object models are different, and the `.Find` is not the same syntax. It is most likely a syntax error you have, but hard to troubleshoot unless you can show your code.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. But storing active cells and so on is not the solution for me. Because the problem is not the search for something while my program is running. The problem is that some macros run in the background on some events. And it is disturbing that CTRL-F is showing the wrong search term and the user does not know why.

Comment: @peter For an example: I use a function to automatically check for double entries.


`Function isSheetContainingString(sh As Object, strString As String) As Boolean`

This function contains mainly 1 simple command:

`Set rngFound = sh.UsedRange.Cells.Find(What:=strString, ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be re-inventing the wheel ...

The `Find & Replace` Dialog Box stores history for you. Just click the drop-down arrow to the right of the text entry box. There a user can grab several search executions worth of history.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I just realize that my search term from the automacro is not in the history even if it is shown as search term. So it's not quite as bad as I thought.